# Where in the BOP does the rental of a building appear?

Tags: international-trade, balance-of-payments

Say a Japanese citizen (living and working in Japan) owns a house in the US and rents it out (to a US resident) for \$10,000 in 2020. (Assume the value of the land is negligible.)

Where in the US BOP does this \$10,000 appear?

I initially thought this should appear under Primary Income (PI). But the BPM6 (p. 178) says

> Rental is also used as a term for the amounts payable under operating leases for produced assets, and
> is a service. ...

> In contrast, rent is used to describe amounts payable under a resource lease covering natural resources, such as land, water, or mineral rights. Rent arising from such resource leases is included in the primary income account

So where does the \$10,000 appear in the US BOP? Should it instead be an import (of services) under the Goods and Services Account?

Comment: Seems like the same situation as dividends - buying a rental property is (simplistically) buying an income stream.